# What's the equivalent of the DictionaryAdapterFactory of Windsor in Ninject?

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, castle-windsor

I'm trying to reproduce the below configuration of Windsor on Ninject.
I know ninject has a factory extension but it's far away from the dictionary adapter that windsor have.

```
WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.AddFacility<Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport.FactorySupportFacility>();

container.Register(
Component.For<IApplicationSettings>().UsingFactoryMethod(
    () => new DictionaryAdapterFactory()
         .GetAdapter<IApplicationSettings>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)));
```

Does anyone know a factory extension for ninject that does dictionary adaptation?

Comment: What is the `DictionaryAdapterFactory` exactly doing?

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit it mapping a interface with properties to a dictionary creating a dynamic proxy I believe.
Full example: http://blog.mirajavora.com/elegant-app-settings-factory/

Comment: Well ninject doesn't feature pre-defined proxy/interceptors for settings access. So you've got to do this yourself (or copy it over from castle). The `UsingFactoryMethod` part is simple enough though (`Bind<IFoo>().ToMethod(x => ...)`).

Comment: I had a look at castle and it would be very hard to copy. I'll try @dave_thieben answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Factory extension allows you to provide your own `IInstanceProvider`. you can use this to return values from the config:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IApplicationSettings>().ToFactory(() => new AppSettingProvider());

        var settings = kernel.Get<IApplicationSettings>();
        Console.WriteLine("One: " + settings.One);
    }
}

public interface IApplicationSettings
{
    string One { get; }
    int Two { get; }
    bool Three { get; }
}

public class AppSettingProvider : Ninject.Extensions.Factory.IInstanceProvider
{
    public object GetInstance(IInstanceResolver instanceResolver, MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        string key = methodInfo.Name;
        if (key.StartsWith("get_"))
            key = key.Substring(4);

        string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
        return Convert.ChangeType(value, methodInfo.ReturnType);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd change the return to Convert.ChangeType(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key], methodInfo.ReturnType); so it can handle integers and booleans for example.